# Runtime error no URI Judge Online?

Tags: c

Não estou conseguindo descobrir o runtime error desse programa. O link da pergunta: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1245

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,k,count,N,M[100];
char L[100];

while ((scanf("%d",&N))!=EOF)
    {for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%d %c",&M[i],&L[i]);
    j=0;
    k=1;
    count=0;
    while(j<N)
        {for(i=k;i<N;i++)
            {if((M[j]==M[i])&&(L[j]!=L[i]))
                ++count;
            if((M[j]==M[i])&&(L[j]==L[i]))
                M[i]=0;
            }
        ++k;
        ++j;
        }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: strongly suggest using `size_t` rather than `int` as none of the values will be less than zero.

Comment: the arrays `M[]` and `L[]` are only 100 elements long BUT `N` can be up to `10*10*10*10` I.E. 10000 in size, so anytime a value for `N` is read that is >= 100, the arrays will overflow (writing past the end of the arrays) which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use meaningful variable names.  Variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both). 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*